# How to compare two revisions in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, version-control

I need to know what files have been added/modified/removed between two revisions. What I do:

```
hg status --rev 10:11
```

It looks okay. But when I have only one revision (initial = 0) it doesn't work.

```
# not work
hg status --rev 0:0
# also not work as I want
hg status --rev 0
```

There is no revision `-1`.

Comment: I don't understand your question because there seems to be a mismatch between what you're saying and what you want. Surely you see that you can't compare two revisions if you only have 1?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The special revision `null` is used to indicate the parent of revision 0.  You can use

```
hg status --rev null:0
```

to see the changes in the first revision.

Answer (score 1):

```
hg status --change [rev]
```

ie,

```
hg status --change 0
```

and

```
hg log -v
```

Comment: I am not sure about it.
 you can see 'hg help status'

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the output of `hg log -v`.  For each changeset, it should list the files modified in that changeset.  If you had a particular changeset in mind, add the `-r` switch to specify it.

Comment: It shows only names of files, without `A|M|R|C` prefixes. Also it show they without `EOL`: `files:       info info1`.